# Windows Mobile : Which icon is the application icon?

Tags: unix, icons

I am trying to write a unix command line utility that will extract the "application" icon from a Windows Mobile executable.  When I look inside the .exe with [wrestool](http://www.nongnu.org/icoutils/) from the icoutils package, I see multiple icon and group_icon resources.  I am trying to figure out which icon the Windows Mobile Programs view would choose to display to the end user.

At first, I figured it would be the icon with name 32512 (IDI_APPLICATION), but then I found several Windows Mobile binaries that lacked this icon resource, but sure enough had visible icons in the Programs view.

Is there a simple but correct algorithm?  like lowest resource id? Is there another resource in the .exe that tells me what is the application icon?  Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's the first `RT_GROUP_ICON` resource in the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Let's show by steps. First, you need to look what is inside your EXE:

```
wrestool -l file.exe
```

Normally, the best icon its the first GROUP_ICON, but when the GROUP_ICONs names are words instead of numbers, then is the GROUP_ICON with the biggest size (or the second biggest size if the first GROUP_ICON is blank, you will need to extract both).

```
wrestool -x -t14 -n(GROUP_ICON name) file.exe > file.ico
```

If you want to create a perfect code, you probably should include the GROUP_ICON language too (sometimes the exe won't have a language (16-bit applications), so you will need to put both of the codes):

```
wrestool -x -t14 -n(GROUP_ICON name) -l(GROUP_ICON language) file.exe > file.ico
```

In some apps, the GROUP_ICON extraction will fail. That's because some new apps (like new games) are using GROUP_ICON as a link, and inserting the real icons inside ICONs. Then, you will need to extract the biggest ICON with that code:

```
wrestool -x -R -t3 -n(ICON name) -o. file.exe > file.ico
```

BUT there will be a BIG problem. That will extract the ICON, but a little part of the file will be missing, which is essential to open this file as an .ico. You will need to open that file in a Hexadecimal Editor and insert in the file a little HEX code before everything else.

```
00 00 01 00 01 00 80 80 00 00 01 00 18 00 28 C8 00 00 16 00 00 00
```

Probably, now you think this is the end. NO. The worse part is coming: extract the correct pic from the ICO. Firstly, you will need not only wrestool, but icotool. Then, use that code:

```
icotool -l file.ico
```

Then, you will need to extract the file with the biggest width, height and bit-depth.

```
icotool -x -o. -w(Width) -h(Height) -b(Bit-depth) file.ico
```

The result will be a PNG file with the perfect icon. Sometimes, that code can fail (Example: The program "Robust Motion Deblurring"), then you will need a second conversor to change from ICO to PNG, but that conversor can fail in some cases (Example: The game "Mass Effect"), so you probably will need both in your code.

I have used that logic in an Objective-C program once, so I know that it's functional (and until now, with 99,9% of success).

Comment: I forgot to say: sometimes, there will be more than one `GROUP_ICON` with the best resources. In that case, if the `name` variable is numeric, the correct one is the number `0`. If `name` is a noun, the correct one is the heavier one (with the biggest `size`).